# How to create a specific logger for my message?

Tags: python, logging

I have spent far too much time on this and I couldn't figure out by myself.

I am writing some code that use some modules, so I want to create a specific logger for my message, not those from the other modules (they are far too many so I don't want to set a different level for each of them).

I have simplified my use case to:

```
import logging                                              
                                                            
logger = logging.getLogger('test')                          
logger.setLevel(level=logging.INFO)                                               
print(logging.Logger.manager.loggerDict)                    
                                                            
logger.debug('This is a debug message')                     
logger.info('This is an info message')                      
logger.warning('This is a warning message')                 
logger.error('This is an error message')                    
logger.critical('This is a critical message')
```

When I execute the previous code, I would expect to have my info message logged.

Instead I got:

```
python3 test.py
{'test': <Logger test (INFO)>}
This is a warning message
This is an error message
This is a critical message
```

Same with `DEBUG`, it always print warning/error/critical messages, not the debug/info.

If I raise the logging level (let's say `ERROR`), it works as expected.

```
python --version
Python 3.9.1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the configuration at the package level / root logger ([documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html#logging.basicConfig)).

```py
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO)
```

Comment: Adding this works, thank you. But I still don't understand why. According to the doc:

````
The functions debug(), info(), warning(), error() and critical() will call basicConfig() automatically if no handlers are defined for the root logger.
```

Answer (score 0):

Using the logging module to record the events:

```
import logging 
  
#Creating an object 
logger=logging.getLogger() 
  
#Setting the threshold of logger to DEBUG 
logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG) 
  
#Test messages 
logger.debug("Debug Message") 
logger.info("An information") 
logger.warning("Warning") 
logger.error("Error message") 
logger.critical("critical Message")
```

Comment: Doesn"t work, this is the code I posted. Debug / Info message never get printed unless logging.basicLogging() is called (see arhr's response).